# Problem on Transpose and Diagonal Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let us define a matrix
$$P = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
2&3&6\\
6&2&{ - 3}\\
{{a_{}}}&b&c
\end{array}} \right)$$
$PP'$ is a diagonal matrix. $\operatorname{Tr}(PAP') = 49$, where in matrix $A = [a_{ij}]$ with
\begin{align}
&  {a_{11}} + {\text{ }}{a_{22}} = 0\\
&{a_{33}} = 1
\end{align}
then which of the statements are true?
\begin{align}
  &{\text{(A) |}}\det (P)| = 343 \hfill \\
  &{\text{(B) }}|a| + |b| + |c| = 11{\text{ }} \hfill \\
  &{\text{(C) }}\operatorname{Tr}(PP') = 147{\text{ }} \hfill \\
  &{\text{(D) }}APP'{\text{ is a diagonal matrix}}
\end{align}
My observations: The answer in my textbook is given as (ABC)}}. What I dread to do in any problem of matrix is to do lengthy multiplication}}. Well, I do not think any such thing is required here. Well when we compute $PP'$, we get the matrix
$$\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {49}&0&{2a + 3b + 6c} \\ 
  0&{49}&{6a + 2b - 3c} \\ 
  {2a + 3b + 6c}&{6a + 2b - 3c}&{{a^2} + {b^2} + {c^2}} 
\end{array}} \right)=\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {49}&0&0 \\ 
  0&{49}&0 \\ 
  0&0&\mu  
\end{array}} \right)$$
Now if we prove $\mu  =  49$ or ${a^2} + {b^2} + {c^2} = 49$  then we can prove (A) and (C) easily. I was not able to dothat and options (B) and (D) are way out of my reach right now I feel. Can anyone help me?

Comment: I really do not know why those extra brackets are appearing in the end. Sorry for poor presentation

Comment: Use that $tr(P A P') = tr(A P' P)$

Comment: You may check the edited text. For a simple introduction to MathJax, please see [https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference/27793#27793]

Comment: Your computation implies that $a = 3 c / 2$ and $b = -3 c$. Use this to simplify the problem.

Comment: What is $P'$? Is it a matrix making $PP'$ diagonal? The heading contain the word transpose but i did not see a transpose of matrix.

Comment: Is there a typo in second row of $P$?

Comment: I rectified . Thanks for bringing it to my notice @RedPhoenix

Comment: P' refers to transpose here

Comment: @Gribouillis I am sorry I am not able to see how that would work

Comment: Shouldn't it be $tr(P' A P)$ instead of $tr(P A P')$ in the hypothesis?

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @griboullis, $P P^T$ is diagonal and $tr(PAP') = tr(PP'A)$

Now $PP' = \begin{bmatrix} 49 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 49 &0 \\
0 & 0 & r  \end{bmatrix}$

So $tr(PP'A) = 49 a_{11} + 49a_{22} + ra_{33} = 49$

and after plugging values you can see that $r = 49$